# Upload/Download de arquivos grandes com ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, file-upload, download, asp.net-core-web-api

Preciso realizar uploads e downlods de arquivos acima de 2GB usando ASP.NET Core 2.2, mas não sei qual a melhor forma de fazer isso. Para o download, to usando o seguinte método:

```
[HttpGet("id")]
public IActionResult Download(Guid id)
{
    // Recupero o caminho físico do arquivo com base no id aqui
    return PhysicalFile(path, MimeTypes.GetMimeType(path), Path.GetFileName(path));
}
```

Aparentemente funciona normal, mas tenho dúvidas quanto ao desempenho ou requisições paralelas. Existe uma abordagem melhor para fazer isso?

Já no upload eu pensei em separar o arquivo em pedaços no lado do cliente e enviar esses pedaços em várias requisições. No lado do servidor eu receberia cada pedaço, gravaria no final do arquivo e enviaria uma resposta para que fosse enviado um novo pedaço. Mas... Essa é realmente uma boa forma de fazer isso? Acho que poderei ter problemas de concorrência ao abrir/fechar o arquivo na hora escrita.

Qual a forma apropriada de realizar downloads/uploads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar um form com [enctype multipart/form-data](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2). Ele suporta arquivos grandes, o envio de arquivos é feito por partes só que é gerenciado pelo navegador.

Disponibilizei um projeto no [GitHub](https://github.com/rafaelchagasb/upload-net-core2-with-progress-bar) com um projeto em Net Core e com a barra de progresso do envio do arquivo para o servidor.

Deixei a versão simplificada do código aqui.

No caso do Net Core você precisa informar qual o tamanho máximo que o seu servidor aceita.

Program.cs

```
public class Program
    {
        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 209715200;
                });
    }
```

Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

         services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
        {
          x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 1209715200;
        });
    }
```

Front

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
action="file" onsubmit="AJAXSubmit(this);return false;" >
            <input type="file" name="file"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />            
    </form>


    async function AJAXSubmit (form) {

    var formData = new FormData($(form)[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: "file",
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Sent');
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
   }
```

Backend

```
[HttpPost]
    [RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 1209715200)]
    [RequestSizeLimit(1209715200)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post(IFormFile file)
    {
        FileStream filestream = new FileStream("/tmp/" + file.FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

            memoryStream.WriteTo(filestream);
        }

        return Ok(new { count = 1, file.FileName, file.Length});
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acabei optando por usar o serviço de armazenamento do Azure, mas obrigado por compartilhar sua resposta.